# How to display a CZI format image using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing

I have an image which I read using `czifile` library.

```
import czifile    
img = czifile.imread("static/Osteosarcoma_01.czi")
print(img.shape)
```

Output:

```
(1, 1, 3, 1104, 1376, 1)
```

Now, I want to display this image using Matplotlib library. How can I do this?

Comment: can you share your czi file link?

Comment: @Karthik [here](https://github.com/bnsreenu/python_for_microscopists/blob/master/images/Osteosarcoma_01.czi) is the image.

Comment: It seems like a 2D color image. Reordering dimensions should suffice.

Answer (score 2):

You have to reshape the raster to (1104, 1376, 3) to be able to display the image. Here is a code:

```
import czifile
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = czifile.imread(file_path)
channels = []
for channel in range(3):
    channel_raster = img[0,0,channel,:,:,0]
    channels.append(channel_raster)
arr = np.stack(channels, axis=2)
plt.imshow(arr)
```

Alternatively, you can use slideio package (http://slideio.com), that can do it for you:

```
import slideio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

slide = slideio.open_slide(file_path, "CZI")
scene = slide.get_scene(0)
plt.imshow(scene.read_block())
```